# ¿Cómo podría hacer para no mostrar filas a los usuarios que están en una tabla específica?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy creando un sitio web donde los usuarios pueden publicar enlaces e interactuar con ellos.

A todos los usuarios se les muestra una tabla con todos los enlaces de los usuarios para poder interactuar con ellos.

Pero necesito hacer una consulta, para que cuando un usuario interactúa con un enlace, ese enlace no se le muestre mas. Es decir, cuando un usuario hace clic en un enlace, el enlace desaparece solo para el usuario que hizo clic.

He hecho lo siguiente.

Tengo la tabla (users) donde se almacenan todos los usuarios.

```
Table1 (users):
----------------
| id | username |
----------------
|  1 |  user1   |
----------------
|  2 |  user2   |
----------------
|  3 |  user3   |
----------------
```

Esta es la segunda tabla donde se almacenan todos los enlaces.

```
Table2 (links):
----------------
| id | urls |
----------------
|  1 |  url1   |
----------------
|  2 |  url2   |
----------------
|  3 |  url3   |
----------------
```

Ahora supongamos que (User2 de la tabla 1 (users)) hizo clic en los siguientes enlaces (URL1 y URL2 de tabla2 (links)).

Cuando el usuario hace clic en una URL, los siguientes valores se almacenan en una tercera tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
Table3 (blockuser):
-----------------------
| id | idLinks | users |
-----------------------
|  1 |    1    | user2 |
------------------------
|  2 |    2    | user2 |
-----------------------
```

Ahora me gustaría que la tabla que contiene todos los enlaces se muestre a cada usuario de la siguiente manera.
Esto es lo que quiero lograr:

```
        User1:                    User2:                   User3:
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
| TABLE: ALL LINKS |      | TABLE: ALL LINKS |     | TABLE: ALL LINKS |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  ID   |  URLS    |      |  ID   |  URLS    |     |  ID   |  URLS    |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  1    |  url1    |      |  3    |  url3    |     |  1    |  url1    | 
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  2    |  url2    |                               |  1    |  url2    |
--------------------                               --------------------
|  3    |  url3    |                               |  1    |  url3    |
--------------------                               --------------------
```

Pero esto es lo que he podido lograr.

```
        User1:                    User2:                   User3:
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
| TABLE: ALL LINKS |      | TABLE: ALL LINKS |     | TABLE: ALL LINKS |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  ID   |  URLS    |      |  ID   |  URLS    |     |  ID   |  URLS    |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  3    |  url3    |      |  3    |  url3    |     |  3    |  url3    | 
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
```

Es decir, cuando un usuario hace clic en un enlace, el enlace ya no se muestra para todos los usuarios.

Pero lo que quiero lograr es que cuando un usuario haga clic en un enlace, el enlace dejará de mostrarse, solo para el usuario que hizo clic en dicho enlace.

Este es el código que tengo para mostrar la tabla:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    links
LEFT JOIN
    blockuser ON blockuser.idLinks = links.id
WHERE
    blockuser.idLinks IS NULL
```

Gracias a todos por su tiempo!

Comment: Solo como referencia, mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]. La pregunta esta muy bien planteada, felicitaciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estas buscando, es mas simple.

La clausula not in, del where, te va a ayudar.

Con ella, podes traer todos los id que estan en una tabla y NO estan en otra

Sabiendo el usuario que entro (IdUsuario), podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
Select * from links 
where id not in (select idlinks from blockuser where users = 'IdUsuario')
```